# How can I use an onclick in a loop on several buttons?

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick

I have 6 buttons that all have the class "test".
I want all of them to display their number, between 1 and 6.

My code is :

```
for (n=0 ; n < document.getElementsByClassName("test").length ; n++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[n].onclick = function() { console.log(n); };
}
```

But my console.log only display "6".
What can I do (with the shortest code possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure inside of `for` loop

```js
for (n = 0; n < document.getElementsByClassName("test").length; n++) {
  (function(i) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(i);
    };
  }(n))
}
```

```html
<div class="test">click</div>
<div class="test">click</div>
```

You could alternatively use `Array.from()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"))
.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="test">click</div>
<div class="test">click</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)